# boost::signals2::scoped_connection::~scoped_connection() can throw exception

Tags: boost

Our coding requirements state don't let exceptions leave the destructor body, but sometimes it's difficult to achieve. The current problem is that boost::signals2::connection::disconnect() function can throw an exception. For me that's strange because scoped_connection also calls 'disconnect()' in the destructor. So, is this a problem of the scoped_connection implementation, or there are some exceptions to the rule "exception must not to leave destructor body"?

BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_68"

An example code snipet can look like this:

```
class Client
{
    Client(Server& server)
    {
        m_connection = server.subscribe([this](const Event& event){  update(event); });
    }
    
    ~Client() noexcept
    {
        m_connection.disconnect();
    }
private:
    void update(const Event& event);

    boost::signals2::connection m_connection;
};
```

Comment: When does disconnect throw? Your code snippet doesn't use `scoped_connection` either. Can you show the actual problem?

Comment: I assume it might throw somewhere in mutex lock. I didnt investigate disconnect() implementation well enough. The issue was found by clang-tidy: " an exception may be thrown in function which should not throw exceptions" after I added disconnect() call in destructor.
scoped_connection is not used but it has the same implementation of the destructor    
_class scoped_connection: public connection { ~scoped_connection() { disconnect(); } }._

Comment: The actual problem is not that exception is actually occured, but that disconnect() function can't be safely used in the destructor. And our code analyses gate can't allow those changes to be applied due to this warning, so I need to fix it in non-pretty way, like using try-catch block

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Are you merely responding to a static analysis warning, or are you actively seeing that `~scoped_connection` throws? Perhaps `clang-tidy` merely objects because `disconnect` isn't marked `noexcept` (which makes sense because it likely didn't exist at the time Signals2 was implemented, as well as Signals2 wants to retain c++03 compatibility). Finally, exactly what is "non-pretty" about try/catch where you need it?

Comment: The actual problem is not that exception has ever been thrown during execution, I have never seen that. But that disconnect() function can't still be safely used in the destructor. And what is weird is that despite of that fact ~scoped_connection() still uses it without try-catch. Also that's hardly possible that clang-tidy rely only on _noexcept_, otherwise it produced too much false positives, nevertheless I dont know for sure. Regarding noexcept: boost library has BOOST_SP_NOEXCEPT macro.

Comment: About non-pretty, I didn't expect that disconnect() produces any exception at all, and I don't like the fact that I should add more complicated code to all the classes which use connection.

Comment: The fact that the macro exists (today) is not to say all code must use it. I don't expect `disconnect` produces an exception at all. You can accept that the program terminate if it happens, or write a letter to the Signals2 maintainers. They're in the best position to see whether you're right and whether it's worth marking the destructor `noexcept`.